# Finding params using leastsq method for levenberg marquardt

Tags: python, parameters, ode, least-squares, levenberg-marquardt

I am trying to plot the data for my leastsq model and equation as I keep getting shape errors. I'm just trying to guess the parameters that fit the data but I can't do that if I can't see the graphs.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
Import numpy as np
Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#data
didata1 = np.loadtxt("diauxic1.txt")
time = didata1[:,0]
pop2 = didata1[:,1]

# model equations
def diauxic_ode(x,t,params):
    r1,r2,k = params  
    y,S1,S2 = x
    derivs = [r1*S1*y+(k/(k+S1))*r2*S2*y, -r1*S1*y, -(k/(k+S1))*r2*S2*y]
    return derivs

# runs a simulation and returns the population size
def diauxic_run(pars,t):
    r1,r2,k,y0,S10,S20 = pars
    ode_params=[r1,r2,k]
    ode_starts=[y0,S10,S20]
    out = odeint(diauxic_ode, ode_starts, t, args=(ode_params,))
    return out[:,0] 

# residual function
def diauxic_resid(pars,t,data):
    r1,r2,k,y0,S10,S20 = pars
    ode_params=[r1,r2,k]
    ode_starts=[y0,S10,S20]
    out = odeint(diauxic_ode, ode_starts, t, args=(ode_params,))
    return diauxic_run(pars,t)-data


p0 =[1,1,1,1,1,1]
lsq_out = leastsq(diauxic_resid, p0, args=(time,pop2))

plt.plot(time,pop2,'o',time,diauxic_resid(p0,time,lsq_out[0]))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate error is the call `diauxic_resid(p0,time,lsq_out[0])`.

- Do you really want to plot the original data and the errors in the same plot?
- The arguments are wrong, both for `resid` and `run`. That something is not right is already clear in having the initial point `p0` in the arguments where you want to plot the adapted result.

Thus replace with `diauxic_run(lsq_out[0],time)`. Or even better, split the plot commands and increase the sample density for the curve

```py
plt.plot(time,pop2,'o');
time = np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], len(time)*10-9)
plt.plot(time,diauxic_run(lsq_out[0], time))
```

[image]

from test data generated by

```
ptest = [0.5, 0.2, 20, 0.2,3.,1.5]
time = np.linspace(0,10,21);
pop2 = diauxic_run(ptest, time)+ np.random.randn(len(time))*0.01
```

leading to fitted parameters

```
lsq_out[0]: [ 0.23199391  0.5998453  20.67961621  0.19636029  2.16841159  2.32688635]
```